# Requests Dialog top position

Tags: facebook

Our Facebook application page allows a user to send invites to the service to a friend using the request dialog.

We do have offline access to the user facebook account so a div is populated with all his friends inside (using ajax).

Each friend gets a "invite" button next to his name, and the request dialog is opened when the user clicks on the button.

IE or FF consistently shows the request dialog in the middle of the browser window, no matter how much scrolled down the user is.

In Chrome, the dialog displays at the top of the page, even if the Request is initiated at the bottom of the page (happens after the friend list is complete).

Because of this, site users do not see the dialog appears and keep re-clicking the invite button, because they can't see the dialog.

Onload:

```
FB.init({
        appId: "00000"
    });
```

Invite click:

```
function sendRequestToRecipients(id) {

    FB.ui({
        method: "apprequests",
        message: "Here's the invite!",
        to: id
    },
    requestCallback);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Applying the following css styling should fix your issue:

```
#FBUIWrapper {position: fixed; top: 0; right: 0; left: 106px;} /* Wrapper to position the invite dialog generated by Facebook */
```

Comment: Had the same problem using the Share dialog through the Facebook JS API, this squared it away nicely.